# ng-bind-html-unsafe is not working for tabset in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to print html output with tabset attribute but nothing is displaying. Apart from this other html is working fine:

```
<tabset> <tab heading="Canada"></tab> <tab heading="International"> </tab> <tab heading="U.S."> </tab> </tabset>


<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="properties.value"></div>
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-bind-html-unsafe` has been removed recently (5 months) from Angular.

See [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/dae694739b9581bea5dbc53522ec00d87b26ae55):

> Changes:
>
> - remove ng-bind-html-unsafe
> - ng-bind-html is now in core
> - ng-bind-html is secure
>
>   - supports SCE - so you can bind to an arbitrary trusted string
>   - automatic sanitization if $sanitize is available

Use `ng-bind-html` instead.

Comment: @user3126031 Describe your issue and create a self contained isolated example. I can't help you if all you say is 'not working'. Please read  [ask] and http://sscce.org/

Comment: That's still not a self contained example... Did you read the links I sent you? I want something that reproduces this problem _with Angular running_. You can set up a short self contained fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net , I personally find those helpful as they help reproduce the problem easily - you can include the library there too (left side)

Comment: <br/> Here is the html value I'm looking output for  <br/>                                                                                            <tabset> <tab heading="Canada"></tab> <tab heading="International"> </tab> <tab heading="U.S."> </tab> </tabset>  <br/>                                   **<div ng-bind-html="properties.value"></div>**

Comment: @user3126031 stop deleting your comment and reposting it - it's not helping you and it's annoying me. Instead, edit your original question. Read my previous and apply the tips "how to ask" provides.

Comment: If you see the output all three tabs(canada, International and US) are missing on http://jsfiddle.net/YGX35/3/

Comment: @user3126031 where is your Angular JavaScript? Where is TabsCtrl? You don't have it in your fiddle.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Might have to use `$sce` service in combination with the new directive `ng-bind-html`.

Comment: @Benjamin added a running code on http://jsfiddle.net/YGX35/5/  and code having issue http://jsfiddle.net/YGX35/6/.